# jQueryUI Buttonset CSS issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

I have a set of Checkboxes that I am using with a Buttonset to make them look like buttons

```
<div id="ButtonList">

    <input type="checkbox" id='Check0' value="true" /><label for="Check0">0000</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id='check1' value='false' /><label for="check1">0100</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id='check2' value='true' /><label for="check2">0200</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id='check3' value='false' /><label for="check3">0300</label>

</div>
```

And

```
$('#ButtonList').buttonset();

$('#ButtonList input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
    $(this).css("color", "red");
});
```

What I want is that when the user clicks the button so that the checkbox under the button is changed the color will change in this case to red.

I have been trying for hours and no luck and google is not helping much either.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to change the style of the buttons, or the style of the checkboxes that are hidden by the buttons? Your current code is adding the **text** color of red to the hidden checkbox elements.

Comment: Change the style of the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current code is adding the text color of red to the hidden checkbox elements and not the styled jQuery UI buttonset.

You can override jQuery UI's default style for active buttons in your list using just CSS.

**JS**

```
$('#ButtonList').buttonset();
```

**CSS**

```
#ButtonList .ui-button.ui-state-active .ui-button-text {
    color: red;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbAwC/1/)

**Update:**

Based on your comments it sounds like you want to use `.each()` to iterate over the items instead of using CSS. You can do that by selecting the correct items and adjusting the styles in JS.

```
$('#ButtonList input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
    var jquiButtonLabel = $(this).next('.ui-button');
    var jquiButtonText = jquiButtonLabel.children('.ui-button-text');
    if (jquiButtonLabel.hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
        jquiButtonText.css({
            'color': 'red',
            'background-color': 'pink'
        });
    } else {
        jquiButtonText.css({
            'color': '',
            'background-color': ''
        });
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbAwC/2/)

Comment: Thanks that makes sense now and yes I know I could add it with CSS but I wanted to control other elements of the button for each button that is added to the group so CSS was not an option.

Comment: Out of interest is there a way to control the CSS or group of the buttons without CSS styling so what I am trying but without the CSS like your jsfiddle?

Comment: @CliffordAgius I added an alternative solution based on your comments.

Comment: The update is exactly what I needed now I can control the buttons as I need.  Thanks